# Rxjs says, Rx.DOM is undefined

Tags: dom, rxjs

I am trying out the simple keypress example,

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');

var source = Rx.DOM.keypress(input);
var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log('Next!');
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

And i have included [rx.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/dist/rx.js) and [rx.binding.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/dist/rx.binding.js) in the index.html. But it says,

`Rx.DOM is undefined`.

I am not seeing `DOM` function in both the rx files as well.

Comment: But you can use smth like: `var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keypress')`

Comment: yup.... this too works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes as a different extension https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM